# Error while exchanging partition in Oracle ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, partitioning

I am trying to swap partition PART_201901 from the `MAIN_TABLE` to the `TABLE_HISTORY`.

I have created the TABLE_HISTORY using the same script as MAIN_TABLE, literally used the same script, indexes, constraints.

My Main_Table has PARTITION BY LIST (YEAR_MONTH) where the YEAR_MONTH is a number field with the value 201901, 201902 etc. and the paritition names are PART_201901  and so on...

- 2 Local Index,
- 1 Local Unique Index,
- 1 PK Constraint using the Local Unique Index.

I am using the below query to exchange the partition:

```
step1: create table tmp_swap  for exchange with table MAIN_TABLE

step2: ALTER TABLE MAIN_TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION PART_201901 WITH TABLE tmp_swap

step3: ALTER TABLE TABLE_HISTORY EXCHANGE PARTITION PART_201901 WITH TABLE tmp_swap
```

I am getting the following error in step3:

```
ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
```

I have reviewed if there is any difference between the 2 tables using the below query and its matching with each other.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH,DATA_PRECISION,COLUMN_ID FROM SYS.dba_tab_cols where table_name = 'MAIN_TABLE'  order by column_id

SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH,DATA_PRECISION,COLUMN_ID FROM SYS.dba_tab_cols where table_name = 'TABLE_HISTORY' order by column_id

select table_Name,search_condition_vc,constraint_type from user_constraints where table_name = 'MAIN_TABLE' order by search_Condition_vc

select table_Name,search_condition_vc,constraint_type from user_constraints where table_name = 'TABLE_HISTORY' order by search_Condition_vc
```

I have checked other answers and I am unable to identify what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The `create table tmp_swap  for exchange with table MAIN_TABLE` command only creates the correct internal column structure. It does not create any dependent objects you may also need.

Because you have a PK on the main table, *you must also have a PK on the swap table*, and it must be enabled so that requires a valid index. Create the unique index on the swap table, add the PK constraint using that index, then retry the exchange

Comment: Hi, I was unable to swap the partition back to my MAIN_TABLE as well. As you recommended I created the PK and now I was able to swap it back, however I am still unable to swap it with TABLE_HISTORY. The same error persists.

Comment: @pOrinG, check the indexing on TABLE_HISTORY and make sure you create any unique local indexes that it has on the swap table (with different names of course).

Comment: Yes, all the indexes, PK constraint are created identically.

Comment: Have you compared *all* the columns from `dba_tab_cols` between your swap table and `table_history`? I notice you aren't looking at `internal_column_id`, `segment_column_id`, `char_length`, `char_used`, `data_scale`,`nullable`, `hidden_column`, `virtual_column` and other important columns. Do a `select *` and look at everything that's not statistics. There's bound to be a discrepancy either in column structure or in constraints or unique indexing. Remember to check *both* the PK index *and* the constraint. They are not the same.